# Django superuser fixture error - no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-syncdb, django-fixtures

I want to define a fixed username and password for superuser creation in  Django's `syncdb` (after it has been executed). The method I'm using below was working in an older version of Django (I guess 1.6) but now it's not working.

I have this fixture file `initial_data.json` :

```
[
{
  "fields": {
    "username": "me",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_superuser": true,
    "is_staff": true,
    "last_login": null,
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": [],
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$...",
    "email": "a@a.co",
    "date_joined": "2015-04-23T01:13:43.233Z"
  },
  "model": "auth.user",
  "pk": 1
}
]
```

when I add this in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',

)
```

and run `python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following error :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture 'path/initial_data.json': Could not load auth.User(pk=1): no such table: auth_user
```

What should I do?

Can I change the order that fixtures load to ensure that `auth_user` table is created before this fixture is loaded?

Or any other way to automatically create a superuser in Django?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does changing `auth.user` to `auth.User` help?

Comment: It is complaining that your database does not have the auth_user table. Can you open up your db and check if that table is there?

Comment: @Cheng I obtained this json file by removing my_app, syncdb and creating superuser manually. So yes it creates the table, but if I include this fixture, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem, however it is definitely not the prettiest solution.

I saw that when I run `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`, I get the following

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: myproject, permissions, myapp1, myapp2
  Apply all migrations: auth, flatpages, admin, contenttypes, sessions, sites
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table app1_model1
    Creating table app1_model2
    ...
```

So I thought what if i migrate the included apps in reverse order :

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate sites; heroku run python manage.py migrate sessions; heroku run python manage.py migrate contenttypes; heroku run python manage.py migrate admin; heroku run python manage.py migrate flatpages; heroku run python manage.py migrate auth;
```

and it worked! I have no idea why, but it did. Maybe this will help someone else too.

Comment: Did you manage to find a prettier solution for this?